# SQL Server - Variable assignment using UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to assign a variable value using UNION ALL but i receive an error:

> Variable assignment is not allowed in a statement containing a top
>   level UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

How can I assign a value using UNION? Here is the sql that i'm trying to make:

```
SELECT @Totals = SUM(Quantity)      
  FROM ConsData A WITH(NOLOCK)      
INNER JOIN #TmpData B ON B.DataId = A.DataId 
INNER JOIN Data cp ON cp.DataId = A.DataId           
 WHERE A.Status = -1 AND cp.Date IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT @Totals = cg.Total  
        FROM ConsDataGenerated cg
            INNER JOIN #TmpData B ON B.DataId = cg.DataId
            INNER JOIN Data cp ON cp.DataId = B.DataId
        WHERE cp.Date IS NULL
```

Comment: I'm assuming that `@Totals` is a scalar variable?, then how are you supossed to assign it 2 different values?

Comment: it is not clear what value do you expect on @totals, as you have two asignments to it

Comment: Have you considered using a SET instead of a select, or removing the top level union by wrapping it into another select?

Comment: I would like to SUM the values from both queries. If i have Date = null, i'll perform 1 select if the Date is not null, i'll do another select.

Comment: @TomTom use SET and perform 2 selects?

Comment: use two variables and add them together?

Comment: @TomTom how can I wrap it into another select?

Comment: First, 2 selects make no sense. THis is logical nonsense. Second, I do not give basic SQL advice - I follow the school of thought that people should read documentation. I told you what to do, figuring out the FROM of a select can be another select - and the exact syntax - is your responsibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this....

```
DECLARE @Totals1 INT, @Totals2 INT, @GrandTotal INT;

SELECT @Totals1 = SUM(Quantity)      
FROM ConsData A WITH(NOLOCK)      
INNER JOIN #TmpData B ON B.DataId = A.DataId 
INNER JOIN Data cp ON cp.DataId = A.DataId           
WHERE A.Status = -1 AND cp.Date IS NOT NULL


SELECT @Totals2 = cg.Total    --<-- Assuming this returns a Scalar value
FROM ConsDataGenerated cg
INNER JOIN #TmpData B ON B.DataId = cg.DataId
INNER JOIN Data cp ON cp.DataId = B.DataId
WHERE cp.Date IS NULL  

SELECT @GrandTotal = ISNULL(@Totals1, 0) + ISNULL(@Totals2, 0);
```